# What does "Peer review in process" mean in ScholarOne submission?

Tags: journals, paper-submission, journal-workflow

I have submitted my manuscript to a journal that uses ScholarOne system. After 20 days, the status is still "Peer review in process". I don't know this means the Reviewers are reviewing my manuscript, or it is still on "Editor's desk"?

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "peer review in process" is vague and could mean anything: for example, the manuscript could be with reviewers, or it could be on the editor's desk, or it could even be that the reviews are complete and it's just waiting for a decision from the editor. There's no way to tell without more info, e.g. what the other statuses of the journal you submitted to are.

Either way there's nothing to do except wait. If you're impatient, write to the journal office and ask.